# Error converting long to Timestamp

Tags: java, datetime, date, timestamp

I'm constructing a java.sql.Timestamp using a long. Sometimes it gets it right other times it gets it wrong! e.g.

76875 gives a Timestamp of "1970-01-01 01:01:16.875"

Where has the extra hour come from? The problem arises and then goes away of its own accord giving:

"1970-01-01 00:01:16.875".

The bit of code causing the problem is running on Google appengine, could it be messing something up with TimeZones? I have tried to identify a pattern but have not managed as yet.

Answer (score 0):

Is the database running on the same server as your app?  A difference in time zone seems most likely.

There are a few variables here.  Try to isolate where the problem is coming from:

1. Construct a Date object with the long timestamp value - is it what you expect?
2. Determine which time zone the App engine server is in.  Maybe new TimeZone().getDisplayName()
3. Try using java.sql.Date - does that behave the same way?

You may want to create a table for yourself of these various date objects.  Try different long values and for each one, create a row of java.util.Date, java.sql.Date, java.sql.Timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

Refresh the memory of `Timestamp` constructor: *the time - milliseconds since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT.* Note, it's **GMT**.

So nothing wrong with "1970-01-01 01:01:16.875", I guess you're in Europe time zone(+1) now:)

Try `new java.sql.Timestamp(76875).toGMTString()`, you will get "1 Jan 1970 00:01:16 GMT".

Also you could call `TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+0:00"));` firstly, then your Timestamp will be "1970-01-01 00:01:16.875".